# How to get an Int input from user in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am currently creating an othello game in Kotlin. I have used Kotlin before in a robotics format, where I really didn't need to display text. Now that I am creating a user Int input to place a piece, I'm not really sure what to do. I've looked everywhere and kept on getting errors. Does anyone know how to do this? (function where I do the input is down below) the rest of the code is here : https://github.com/Spanini2/othello

```
fun main() {
    var board = othelloBoard
    var cPlayer = 'X'

    setupBoard(board)

    while (true) {
        showBoard(board)
        println("It is player $cPlayer 's turn")
        println("Enter coords of move:")
        var xInput = readLine()!!.toInt()
        var yInput = readLine()!!.toInt()
        placePiece(board, xInput, yInput, cPlayer)
    }

}
```

Comment: "kept on getting errors". What are the errors? The code to read input looks fine. Work on the error, not on what you try to achieve. Learn how to debug

Comment: The repo you linked is just a Hello World.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out...its because I was using the kotlin web playground. I was using it because I was having other problems with VS code. I generally use Android Studio, but I code mainly at school with a school issued laptop...which has blocked Andoid Studio. :(